# Picking color randomly

Tags: probability

I have $7$ colors (white, black, green, orange, yellow, blue and red). I pick $3$ of them at random, and whichever color is drawn already is eliminated from the pool. What is the probability to draw each color?

I know for the first color, say red, the probability is $\frac 1 7$, correct?  But once it has been eliminated, what is the probability of drawing each other color for the next two draws?

Answer (score 2):

Let choose black as our favorite colour.

In the first round, you have a $\frac{1}{7}$ chance of picking black, in the second round, you have a $\frac{1}{6}$ chance of picking black, but only if you have not picked black already, which is a $\frac{6}{7}$ chance, so the chance of getting black in the second round is $\frac{6}{7} \times \frac{1}{6} = \frac{1}{7}$. In the last round, you have a $\frac{6}{7} \times \frac{5}{6} \times \frac{1}{5} =\frac{1}{7}$ chance of picking black, since you must pick a different colour in the first two rounds, and black in the last round.

So the chance of picking black is $\frac{1}{7} + \frac{1}{7} + \frac{1}{7} = \frac{3}{7}$, as is the chance of any other colour.

Comment: Nice! Perhaps simpler (or more 'automatic'), if one is used to 'combinations': Imagine an urn with 7 balls, one of each color. There are $T = {7 \choose 3}$ ways to choose three balls without replacement. The number of ways to choose exactly one black and two of other colors is $B = {1 \choose 1}{6 \choose 2}.$ Probability is $P(\text{1 black} )= B/T = 3/7.$

Answer (score 2):

I wonder why all this computation is necessary. Suppose we transform the problem to:

*7 candidates are interviewed and 3 are to be selected*

What is the probability that you are selected ?

Just $\dfrac37$, that's all !

Answer (score 1):

If we take your given set of seven colors, and we want to draw red, and we draw three colors...

First, there is as you say, a probability of drawing red equal to $\frac17$.

If at first we do not draw red, there are six colors left. Not drawing red first is $\frac67$ and subsequently drawing red is $\frac16$. Multiply those to get $\frac6{42}=\frac17$.

If we don't draw red twice, which only happens with probability $\frac67×\frac56=\frac{30}{42}=\frac57$, then we have a remaining probability of $\frac15$. Multiplied together, that again gives $\frac17$.

Since these three classes of outcomes are disjoint, we can add their probabilities directly. The scenario you describe happens exactly $\frac37$ of the time.

That's a long way to go around, eh?

Let's put this problem another way: You draw all the colors. What's the probability that the red is in the first three draws? You can draw red in seven different ways: first, second, third, fourth, fifth, sixth, and seventh. Only three of those are first, second, or third. Ergo, $\frac37$.